# I can not alter is_accessible in Flask-admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

After having is_accessable return false, I can still access the User table. What am I doing wrong?

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))

class MyModelView(ModelView):
    def is_accessible(self):
        return False    


admin = Admin(app)
admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session))
```

Answer (score 0):

You created `MyModelView` but used `ModelView` when adding the view.

Change

```py
admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session))
```

to

```py
admin.add_view(MyModelView(User, db.session))
```